# Triggering Flow I'm not prompted for require variables

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, json-formatting

I'm triggering a Flow from a SharePoint library following [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/272263/27208), basically json column formatting with a `customRowAction`. That part works fine and I've used it many different times.

I'm using the *Manually trigger a flow* as the trigger and have added some required user inputs. [image: trigger with user inputs]. If I manually test the flow, it brings up the dialog for user input. But if I trigger the flow by clicking on the link in my library it doesn't request user input — so of course the flow doesn't work because the inputs are required.

I've tried copying my flow and even creating a new one; changing the guid in the customRowAction each time. The flows always start and if I check the run information it shows it ran, but the required user inputs are never displayed.

I've also cleared my cache and tried different browsers -- chrome, edge, even IE 11.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not seeing any MS article on this, but noticing the same behavior for **Manually trigger a flow**. I would recommend using **For a selected file** or **For a selected item** trigger instead. When JSON formatting is used to run these types of Flow by selecting a file or item, the Run-Flow panel is opened up for the input values.
Also, noticing that no **Manually** trigger flows are available in the dropdown menu under **Automate**, but others types are available to run.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Per my test it's same issue with you, column formatting button will not pop up
input text box when we use "Manually trigger a flow".

So I think "Manually trigger a flow" will only works at flow dashboard, if you want to manually trigger a flow in SharePoint page, change the trigger to "For a selected item", which will pop up the input text.

[image]

[image]

For information about Microsoft SharePoint Connector in Power Automate for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#for-a-selected-item